# How can I expand width of UIView from left to right - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a `UIView` and I've added a UIView inside it as a subview. I'm hoping to expand the subview to fill a portion of the view, as a percentage, for example:

`subview.bounds.width = view.bound.width(num1/max)`

where `num1` changes every second until it reaches max.

Comment: That is a horrible way to animate a view expansion. Please read up on view animations [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UIView's frame can't be partially changed - to get the result you're looking for, you need to create a new frame, manipulate it, *then* attach it to your subview, like so:

```
let newFrame = subview.frame
newFrame.size.width = view.frame.width * num1 / max
subview.frame = newFrame
```